# I am trying to automate the new windows instance provisioning in AWS with codedeploy but facing the issue with codedeploy in deployment stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-auto-scaling

CodeDeploy error:

> Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - C:\ProgramData/Amazon/CodeDeploy/bacdf85d-5ead-4848-88a5-2df57e45865d/d-N5CXXL6Y1/deployment-archive/C:\

appspec.yaml file:

```
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: /
    destination: C:\windows-scripts
hooks:
  SoftwareInstall:
    - location: scripts\installation.ps1
      timeout: 300
      runas: administrator
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts\connect.ps1
      timeout: 1200
      runas: administrator
```

How to resolve this issue?

I tried by updating the lifecycle hooks and ASG configuration but it is not working.